# Analogue of the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem for general algebraic structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

The Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem states that if there are two sets $A$ and $B$ such that there exist injective (alternatively, surjective, assuming choice I think) maps $A \to B$ and $B \to A$, then $A$ and $B$ are in bijection.  It then seems natural to try to strengthen the result to other structures.  If $A$ and $B$ are, say, groups (or rings, modules, etc) such that there are injective homomorphisms from each to the other, then $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic.

I'm wondering if there are any results on this, or if there are known counterexamples.  The theorem for sets alone is nontrivial, so I feel like any results about how it holds for other structures would be quite interesting.

Comment: Just as a quick counterexample to "groups, rings, modules, etc.": if $G$ is the direct product of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, then there is a natural injection $G \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times G$ via inclusion in the second coordinate, and there is an injection $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times G \to G$ via $1 \mapsto 2$ in the first coordinate and identity in all other coordinates.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  Both those comments together pretty much completely answer my question.  I guess I'll accept if either of you posts them as an answer.

Comment: I think it interesting that this theorem can be proven without using the axiom of infinity. I conjecture that it's possible to prove the theorem for proper classes $A$ and $B$, but only by accepting the axiom of infinity.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is an interesting topic, and has been studied in many contexts. See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold/) in MO for examples, counterexamples, and some links to the literature (far from exhaustive). In the context of model theory, John Goodrick (the author of the answer in the link above) has [several papers](http://matematicas.uniandes.edu.co/~goodrick/research.html) on this topic, including his PhD dissertation.

One typically refers to these analogues as the (Cantor)-Bernstein-Schröder property: Given a class $C$ of objects and a class $\mathcal F$ of maps between them, the *Bernstein-Schröder property* for $C,\mathcal F$ means that if $X,Y$ are objects in $C$ and $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ are injections in $\mathcal F$, then there is a bijection in $\mathcal F$ between $X$ and $Y$. Typically, $C$ and $\mathcal F$ form a category, and the sought-after bijections would be equivalences in the category. This reformulation suggests further generalizations.

Here are some examples:

- The class $C$ of well-orderings, with $\mathcal F$ the class of order-preserving maps.
- The class of Polish spaces, with Borel maps.
- (Assuming the axiom of choice.) The class of vector spaces (over a fixed field $K$), with $K$-linear maps. (Let me prove this, as the argument is simple enough. Note that if there is a linear injection $T:V\to W$, then any linearly independent set in $V$ is mapped to a linearly independent set in $W$. In particular, if $V$ and $W$ have a basis (as is the case under choice), then the dimension of $V$ is less than or equal than that of $W$. Hence, if there are linear injections $T:V\to W$ and $S:W\to V$, then $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension, and any bijection between a basis of $V$ and one of $W$ uniquely extends to a $K$-isomorphism between the spaces.)

The category of groups with group homomorphisms is an example of a category without the 
Bernstein-Schröder property. For example, consider $G=\bigoplus_{n\in\omega}\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and $H=G\oplus \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, where $\oplus$ denotes direct sum. There are monomorphisms from $G$ into $H$ and from $H$ into $G$, but $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic. (This is actually a typical example. I just noticed—after typing it—that this is precisely the example given in a comment above.)

Comment: Thanks.  I guess one other interesting question would be: Are there situations in ZFC where monomorphisms $A \to B$ and $B \to A$ are sufficient to get an isomorphism but epimorphisms are not, or visa-versa?

Comment: Do we know about the category of fields?

Comment: @mez, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold.