# Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ of rank $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I found from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257650/analogue-of-the-cantor-bernstein-schroeder-theorem-for-general-algebraic-structu) that groups $A \supset B \supset C$ with $A \simeq C$ does not imply $A\simeq B$. How about the case of $A\simeq \mathbb{Z}^n$? Is it still false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subgroups of free abelian groups are free abelian and have smaller (or equal) rank.

Answer (score 1):

In that special case, it is true. In particular, $B$ will necessarily be a [free abelian group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group) of rank $n$.