# If there monomorphisms $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g : B \rightarrow A$ then there is an isomorphism $h : A \rightarrow B$

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

Consider the following set theoretical result of Schröder-Bernstein-Cantor:

Let $A$, $B$ be sets. Assume we have injections $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g : B \rightarrow A$. Then there exists a bijection $h : A \rightarrow B$.

Although this fact seems obvious, its proof is not completely trivial (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) ) But what about the following statements?

- Let $A$ and $B$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces. Assume we have monomorphisms $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g : B \rightarrow A$. Then there exists an isomorphism $h : A \rightarrow B$. (true)
- Let $A$ and $B$ be vector spaces. Assume we have monomorphisms $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g : B \rightarrow A$. Then there exists an isomorphism $h : A \rightarrow B$. (true?)
- Let $A$ and $B$ be Hilbert spaces. Assume we have monomorphisms $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g : B \rightarrow A$. Then there exists an isomorphism $h : A \rightarrow B$. (true)
- Let $A$ and $B$ be groups. Assume we have monomorphisms $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g : B \rightarrow A$. Then there exists an isomorphism $h : A \rightarrow B$. (true?)

How far can you generalize the original result of Schröder-Bernstein-Cantor, at least in categories where monomorphisms are injective and isomorphisms are bijective?

Comment: For groups, if you replace monomorphism with surjective then this is not true. Hope it helps somehow.

Comment: Related / possible duplicates: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/257650/, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/672343/

Comment: And more discussion [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold/) and [here](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/theme-and-variations-schroeder-bernstein/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For groups this is not true. Let $F_n$ be the free group with $n$ generators, then $F_2$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $F_3$ and obviously $F_3$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $F_2$.