# Field homomorphism in both directions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If $E$ and $F$ are two fields and $f : E \to F$ and $g : F \to E$ be field homomorphisms. Is it true that $E$ and $F$ are isomorphic?

We know that both $f$ and $g$ are injective which prompts the question.

**EDIT:** As pointed out in comments and other posts, this is not true in general. Are there any conditions on $E$, $F$ which makes this result true? Algebraically closed, characteristic zero, positive etc.?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257650/analogue-of-the-cantor-bernstein-schroeder-theorem-for-general-algebraic-structu.

Comment: Noah Snyder in the comments of the SBS blog post linked in the MO thread that lhf links ^ gives the example of $\Bbb C(x)$ and $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @arctictern It wasn't Noah Snyder who gave that example but Scott Carnahan instead, but thanks nonethless.

Comment: Oops, being silly. Sorry Scott.

Comment: no because you always got the trivial homomorphism.

Comment: @ZelosMalum There is no trivial homomorphism of fields . . .